# How to force chrome.tabs.query returns a value?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

is it possible to get value from chrome.tabs.query(...) or chrome.tabs.getSelected(...)
Because now it's

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, function(tabs){
    var indx = tabs[0].index;
    chrome.tabs.create({url: getPageUrl(), index : indx });
});
```

but I need similar to

```
function getCurrentIndex(){
    return chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, function(tabs){
        var indx = tabs[0].index;
        return indx;
    })
}
chrome.tabs.create({url: getPageUrl(), index : getCurrentIndex() });
```